# browser.getCurrentUrl() is giving me "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning" in only one Test

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, e2e-testing

I changed my Tests to async/await and since then browser.getCurrentUrl() is working fine, except in this Test:

```
        (Filling out a Form)
        ...
        await element(by.id('auftrag-disponieren')).click();

        await browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf($('list')), 1000).catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });

        since('How it should be, but is #{actual}').
          expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("https://someRandomDomain.com");

      })
    });
```

throwing the following warning but still passes the test:

```
>(node:13760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
    at runWaitForAngularScript.then (C:\Users\mat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:463:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:13760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13760) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:13760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
    at runWaitForAngularScript.then (C:\Users\mat\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\browser.js:463:23)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:13760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
```

I̶f̶ ̶I̶ ̶g̶e̶t̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶u̶r̶r̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶u̶r̶l̶ ̶b̶e̶f̶o̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶l̶i̶c̶k̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶f̶a̶i̶l̶s̶,̶ ̶s̶o̶ ̶i̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶b̶e̶c̶a̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶f̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶d̶i̶r̶e̶c̶t̶.̶ ̶P̶l̶a̶c̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶-̶c̶a̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶b̶l̶o̶c̶k̶ ̶a̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶w̶o̶n̶'̶t̶ ̶h̶e̶l̶p̶ ̶e̶i̶t̶h̶e̶r̶.̶ ̶

I use `browser.getCurrentUrl()` several times in different tests but this is the only one where I get this warning.

**Edit:**

Disabling the `since()` function and trying to `await expect(..).toContain(..)` did not help. I got the same result as before.

I maybe should have mentioned that I have the following function

`afterAll(async () => {
    await browser.get("https://someRandomDomain.com/dashboard")
  })`

**Edit2:**

I think the warnings originate from the `afterAll(async () => {await browser.get("https://someRandomDomain.com/dashboard")})` function. Since commenting this line out I don't get these warnings. But still I use this function in diffrent tests and they won't throw these warnings.

Comment: Is that error getting logged from your browser.wait? This could be a case of the page loading too quickly and angular not being found but based on the fact that there is a 1 second wait this is very unlikely. Are there other tests which interact with this page that pass successfully?

Comment: @DublinDev it's not because of the browser.wait I disabled the logging and it still appears. I mean I could run the same test without the "browser.getCurrentUrl" and it won't give me these warnings. And even tho I get these warnings the test passes/fails accordingly.

Comment: What I meant was that if the error was getting logged from that `browser.wait().catch()` statement then you know that page is not loading as you are expecting it to and therefore the `expect` will fail. If that error is not getting logged then you have a separate issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing afterAll to:

```
afterAll(async () => {
        await browser.driver.get("https://someRandomDomain.com/dashboard");
        await browser.driver.sleep(1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
    since('How it should be, but is #{actual}').
      await browser.waiForAngularEnabled(false);//true if your application is angular
      await expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain("https://someRandomDomain.com");

  })
```

Comment: Sadly it did not work, I got the same result. And it is an angular page

Comment: @Moke did you try with  `await browser.waiForAngularEnabled(true);` add this before loading your application url

Answer (score 0):

Try `await` before `expect`:

```
await expect(...).toContain(...);
```